# Replace a string in a URL with python

Tags: python, regex

I have a text containing a URL that needs to be reworked.

```
text='dfs:/?url=https://myserver/c12&ofg={"tes":{"id":1812}}'
```

I need to replace programmatically the id value (in this example 1812, which is unknown before the execution) with a fixed substring (e.g. 189). So the end result must be

```
'dfs:/?url=https://myserver/c12&ofg={"tes":{"id":189}}'
```

As I'm programming in Python, I guess that I should use the regular expression (module re) to automatically replace that value between "id": and }} but I couldn't find one that works for this use case.

Comment: You give no insights on how this URL is constructed; which parts are always the same and which do change.

Comment: `text.replace('1812','189')` might work.

Comment: you are right, I have edited the question.  The one that should change is between "id":    and }} . All the rest should remain the same

Comment: `text.replace('{"id":1812}', '{"id":189}')` or `text.replace('{"tes":{"id":1812}}', '{"tes":{"id":189}}')` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are always generating the same URL with that pattern, and the value to 'change' is always in *{"id":X}*. One way to solve this particular problem is with a positive lookbehind + re.sub replacement.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=\"id\":)\d+")
string = "dfs:/?url=https://myserver/c12&ofg={\"tes\":{\"id\":1812}}"

print(pattern.sub("desired_value", string))
```

Generated output will contain desired_value in place of the 1812. A good explanation of what is happening is done in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2SoeTC/1) but a quick rep of what is happening in the pattern:

- Matches any digit one or more times ONLY if behind has ***"id":***, without consuming characters

Comment: Another alternative, if you want to exercise yourself, is matching digits (play on regex101) then, once you find which number you have there, you can do a replace on the string.

Answer (score 0):

what about simply splitting the string twice? eg.

```
my_string = 'dfs:/?url=https://myserver/c12&ofg={"tes":{"id":1812}}'
substring = my_string.split('"id":',1)[1]
substring  = substring.split('}}')[0]
print(my_string.replace(substring, "189"))
```